# How to center a bootstrap row containing 3 images?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a container-fluid that contains 3 row

Row 1: 4 images
Row 2: 4 images
Row 3: 3 images

I am trying to center Row 3, I tried adding Row 3 inside another class called "container" and tried the "left, right" in css but did not work, may you please help?

```css
.b3 {
 padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.client-section {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
}

.img-responsive {
 padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#clients  {padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:50px;color: #7e7e7e; background-color:#151515;}
```

```html
<section class="container-fluid client-section" id="clients">
    <div class="row">
        <div>
          <b class="col-lg-10
            col-md-10
            col-sm-10
            col-xs-10
            col-lg-push-1
            col-md-push-1
            col-sm-push-1
            col-xs-push-1 b2 b3">Clients</b>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-10
            col-md-10
            col-sm-10
            col-xs-10
            col-lg-push-1
            col-md-push-1
            col-sm-push-1
            col-xs-push-1">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="imgs/UserImage.png" width="200" height="200" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="imgs/UserImage.png" width="200" height="200" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="imgs/UserImage.png" width="200" height="200" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="imgs/UserImage.png" width="200" height="200" />
  </div>
 </div>
 
 
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="imgs/UserImage.png" width="200" height="200" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="imgs/UserImage.png" width="200" height="200" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="imgs/UserImage.png" width="200" height="200" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="imgs/UserImage.png" width="200" height="200" />
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="row center">
  <div class="col-lg-3">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="imgs/UserImage.png" width="200" height="200" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="imgs/UserImage.png" width="200" height="200" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="imgs/UserImage.png" width="200" height="200" />
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this your solution

```css
.b3 {
 padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.client-section {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
}

.img-responsive {
 padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.center .img-responsive{
  margin:0 auto;
  display:block;
  }

#clients  {padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:50px;color: #7e7e7e; background-color:#151515;}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="imgs/UserImage.png" width="200" height="200" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="imgs/UserImage.png" width="200" height="200" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="imgs/UserImage.png" width="200" height="200" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="imgs/UserImage.png" width="200" height="200" />
  </div>
 </div>
 
 
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="imgs/UserImage.png" width="200" height="200" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="imgs/UserImage.png" width="200" height="200" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="imgs/UserImage.png" width="200" height="200" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="imgs/UserImage.png" width="200" height="200" />
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="row center">
  <div class="col-lg-3">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="imgs/UserImage.png" width="200" height="200" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="imgs/UserImage.png" width="200" height="200" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="imgs/UserImage.png" width="200" height="200" />
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Yes, Almost like that but for the last row!!

Comment: Can't get you.. What do you want in the last row

Comment: you gave me a code that centers all the images/rows, I want to center only the last row/3 images.

Comment: Updated. Check it again

Answer (score 0):

The last row have 9, need to be 12, replace 3 by 4.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="imgs/UserImage.png" width="200" height="200" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="imgs/UserImage.png" width="200" height="200" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="imgs/UserImage.png" width="200" height="200" />
    </div>
</div>
```

And change the css by this:

```
.img-responsive {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    display:block;      
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto 
}
```

Comment: did you change the css of the .img-responsive to center the img?

Answer (score 0):

you can use bootstrap class `text-center`

or you can just add this css

```
.center{
   text-align: center;
}
```

```css
.b3 {
 padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.client-section {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
}

.img-responsive {
 padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#clients  {padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:50px;color: #7e7e7e; background-color:#151515;}

.center{
   text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="container-fluid client-section" id="clients">
    <div class="row">
        <div>
          <b class="col-lg-10
            col-md-10
            col-sm-10
            col-xs-10
            col-lg-push-1
            col-md-push-1
            col-sm-push-1
            col-xs-push-1 b2 b3">Clients</b>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-10
            col-md-10
            col-sm-10
            col-xs-10
            col-lg-push-1
            col-md-push-1
            col-sm-push-1
            col-xs-push-1">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="imgs/UserImage.png" width="200" height="200" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="imgs/UserImage.png" width="200" height="200" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="imgs/UserImage.png" width="200" height="200" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="imgs/UserImage.png" width="200" height="200" />
  </div>
 </div>
 
 
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="imgs/UserImage.png" width="200" height="200" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="imgs/UserImage.png" width="200" height="200" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="imgs/UserImage.png" width="200" height="200" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="imgs/UserImage.png" width="200" height="200" />
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="row center">
  <div class="col-lg-3">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="imgs/UserImage.png" width="200" height="200" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="imgs/UserImage.png" width="200" height="200" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="imgs/UserImage.png" width="200" height="200" />
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>
</section>
```